# Ruby method that returns an age from a date of birth

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails

I have a method on my user model to calculate the user's age and return a human readable string.  My user's can be between 1 month old and above so the returned string is different depending on if the person is "2 months old" or "1 year old" or "2 years and 3 months old".

I have reviewed a few SO posts to come to this solution.  Is there anything I am missing?  Leap years?

```
def age
    dob = self.date_of_birth

    # if a date of birth is not nil
    if dob != nil 

      # get current date  
      now = Date.current

      # has person had their birthday yet this year
      had_birthday = ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? true : false) 

      # if yes then subtract this year from birthday year, if not then also subtract 1 to get how many full years old they are
      years = now.year - dob.year - (had_birthday ? 0 : 1)

      # get the calendar month difference from birthdya calendar month and today's calendar month.  if they have not had their birthdya yet then subtract the difference from 12
      months = had_birthday ? now.month - dob.month : 12 - (now.month - dob.month)

      # for under 1 year olds
      if years == 0
        return months > 1 ? months.to_s + " months old" : months.to_s + " month old"  

      # for 1 year olds
      elsif years == 1
        return months > 1 ? years.to_s + " year and " + months.to_s + " months old" : years.to_s + " year and " + months.to_s + " month old" 

      # for older than 1
      else
        return months > 1 ? years.to_s + " years and " + months.to_s + " months old" : years.to_s + " years and " + months.to_s + " month old"
      end

    # No date of birth saved so can not calculate age
    else
      return "No Date of Birth"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'd just use https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Make an additional function  to handle plural

In-lining the extra logic to handle the plural is messy, I suggest a small separate method:

```
def plural(word, value)
  "#{value.to_s} #{word}#{value > 1 ? 's' : ''}"
end
```

#### Reduce nesting by returning early

If you write

```
if dob == nil
  return "No Date of Birth"
end
```

You can reduce nesting in the rest of the function and highlight the handling of the special case.

Comment: Or `return "No Date of Birth" if dob.nil?` to reduce even more nesting. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this line:

```
months = had_birthday ? now.month - dob.month : 12 - (now.month - dob.month)
```

should be:

```
months = had_birthday ? now.month - dob.month : 12 - (dob.month - now.month)
```

For example, if today is 2016-June-31 and the dob is 2015-Dec-31, `now.month - dob.month` will be "-6". `12 - (-6) = 18` making the result "18 months old" instead of "6 months old".

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm not sure why someone downvoted you, this is a real bug that you've found, nice work!

Comment: Thanks @SuperBiasedMan! I was also wondering why it was downvoted

Answer (score 2):

To facilitate unit testing, I recommend putting this code in a parameterized function in a helper module.  Your application can then call that function with `self.date_of_birth` as an argument.

There are a lot of conditionals in your logic.  If you want an interval with month resolution, then it would be a lot simpler to compute the difference in months first.  It would also be smarter to compose the text rather than enumerate all the possible combinations.

`today` would be a better variable name than `now`, since the `Date` object only has day resolution.

By [English pluralization rules](//english.stackexchange.com/a/13075/16310), "0 months old" would be more correct than "0 month old".

```
module Helper
  def age(dob, today=nil)
    return "No date of birth" if dob.nil?
    today ||= Date.current

    month_diff = (12 * today.year + today.month) - (12 * dob.year + dob.month)
    y, m = month_diff.divmod 12

    y_text =      (y == 0) ? nil : (y == 1) ? '1 year'  : "#{y} years"
    m_text = y && (m == 0) ? nil : (m == 1) ? '1 month' : "#{m} months"
    [y_text, m_text].compact.join(' and ') + ' old'
  end
end
```

Comment: small improvement: `y, m = month_diff.divmod 12`.  also, won't this make someone whose birthday was the last day of a month "1 month" old on the first of the next month?  and someone born on the first will still be 0 on the last day of the month?  in fairness, it's not clear from the OP what the desired behavior is

Comment: Great suggestion and yes I didn't identify all of the edge cases I should for testing.  Thanks for identifying the first and last of month scenario.